# How do i extract and save a base64 byte array from an xml document in python

Tags: python, arrays, xml

I have an XML file that contains images stored as base64 byte arrays.

I want to extract the arrays and save as image files

I can get the array from the XML as a string like so

```
 photo=record.find('Photo').text.tobase64
```

but I cannot work out how to output the image

```
 picpath = '..\\pics\\' + upn +'.jpg'
f = open(picpath, 'wb')
f.write(photo)
f.close()
```

complains about the photo being a string.

I am obviously missing something, but I cannot work out what

EDIT

the error

----> 7     f.write(photo)
8     f.close()
9

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

and the XML (a truncated version of the byte array though)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> 
<Record> <Photo>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ</Photo>
 <ID>E9282</ID> 
</Record>
```

Comment: can you share the xml or a valid subset of it?

Comment: i can share the structure, but not the data - far too confidential to allow out into the wild.

Comment: share what you can.. A fake photo base64 byte arrays can help.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
  <Record>
  <Photo>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ</Photo>
 
    <ID>E9282</ID>
    
  </Record>

Comment: thats a massively truncated version of the byte array

Comment: Edit the question instead of adding a comment with XML data. It is better if all information is in the question. Provide a proper [mcve], including `import` statements.

Comment: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' -- >`img_data = root.find('.//Photo').text.encode('utf-8')`